# Function stops working after retrieving localStorage

Tags: javascript

I'm using localStorage on two lists, fruit-shelf & fruit-basket.

If you click on a fruit from fruit-shelf, it appends it to the fruit-basket, and if you refresh the page it's still there — so it remembers everything as it should.

**Problem is:** if you add one fruit, and then refresh page, you can't add more fruits, the program completely stops working.

I've added a Clear Local Storage button, which works. If you click on it and refresh page, you can add fruits again. But as soon as one fruit is added and you refresh page, you can't add more items to the fruit-basket.

I'm not sure how to put a name on the problem so it's hard to search for solutions (I've tried!).

Can someone point me in the right direction? :-)

**Fiddle** (I couldn't use SO Snippet here because of localStorage):
https://jsfiddle.net/nrv269hc/7/

**JS:**

```
(function() {

  var btnClearStorage = document.querySelector('.btn-delete-all');
  var fruitShelf = document.querySelector('.fruit-shelf');
  var fruitShelfItems = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-shelf li');
  var fruitBasket = document.querySelector('.fruit-basket');

  // Store current state of fruitSheflf & fruitBasket
  function storestate() {
    localStorage.fruitShelf = fruitShelf.innerHTML;
    localStorage.currentFruitBasket = fruitBasket.innerHTML;
  };

  function retrievestate() {

    // Retrieve fruits left from shelf
    if (localStorage.fruitShelf) {
      fruitShelf.innerHTML = localStorage.fruitShelf;
    }
    // Retrieve stored fruits 
    if (localStorage.currentFruitBasket) {
      fruitBasket.innerHTML = localStorage.currentFruitBasket;
    }
  };

  retrievestate();

  for (var i = 0; i < fruitShelfItems.length; i++) {

    fruitShelfItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      fruitBasket.appendChild(this);
      storestate();
    });

  }

  // Clear Local Storage
  btnClearStorage.addEventListener('click', function() {

    localStorage.clear(fruitShelf);
    localStorage.clear(fruitBasket);

  });

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the fruitShelfItems as the HTML is update after retrievestate.

Look at updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrv269hc/10/)

```
(function() {

  var btnClearStorage = document.querySelector('.btn-delete-all');
  var fruitShelf = document.querySelector('.fruit-shelf');
  var fruitShelfItems = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-shelf li');
  var fruitBasket = document.querySelector('.fruit-basket');

  // Store current state of fruitSheflf & fruitBasket
  function storestate() {
    localStorage.fruitShelf = fruitShelf.innerHTML;
    localStorage.currentFruitBasket = fruitBasket.innerHTML;
  };

  function retrievestate() {

    // Retrieve fruits left from shelf
    if (localStorage.fruitShelf) {
      fruitShelf.innerHTML = localStorage.fruitShelf;
    }
    // Retrieve fruit basket
    if (localStorage.currentFruitBasket) {
      fruitBasket.innerHTML = localStorage.currentFruitBasket;
    }
    // you need to update the fruitShelfItems as the HTML is update after retrievestate
    fruitShelfItems = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-shelf li');
  };

  retrievestate();

  for (var i = 0; i < fruitShelfItems.length; i++) {

    fruitShelfItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

      fruitBasket.appendChild(this);
      storestate();
    });

  }

  // Clear Local Storage
  btnClearStorage.addEventListener('click', function() {

    localStorage.clear(fruitShelf);
    localStorage.clear(fruitBasket);

  });

})();
```

Comment: Of course, how could I overlook that! Thank you Badr! :)